# MySQL ORDER BY order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

In MySQL, is there a difference between those 2 queries?

```
SELECT * FROM .... ORDER BY Created,Id DESC
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM .... ORDER BY Created DESC, Id DESC
```

Desired behaviour: order (descending ) by "Created" ( a timestamp) but when two items have the same "Created" value then fall back to ordering ( desc ) using the Id.

Comment: Then use the second one.  The first one is the same as: `ORDER BY Created ASC, Id DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.  The default order is ascending, so:

```
SELECT * FROM .... ORDER BY Created,Id DESC
```

Will order by `Created` ascending, and then `Id` descending

```
SELECT * FROM .... ORDER BY Created DESC, Id DESC
```

Will order by `Created` descending, and then `Id` descending

Answer (score 0):

Of course there's a difference. The first orders by `CREATED` in ascending order, and then if there are multiples sorts those rows on `ID` descending. The second sorts by `CREATED` in descending order first, then by `ID` descending if there are multiples.

The second one should do what you want.

(Of course, this begs the question: Why didn't you just try it yourself to find out?)

Answer (score 0):

I think first one wont work?

You could do

```
SELECT * FROM .... ORDER BY Created ASC, Id DESC
SELECT * FROM .... ORDER BY Created DESC, Id ASC
```

but it will slow down slightly if you do different ones.

Comment: The first one will work; if no sort order is specified, `ASC` is used.

Answer (score 0):

In the first one, the default ordering(`ASC`) is used for `Created` column.

Answer (score 0):

The defult sorting for dates is in ASC - Ascending order.

So the 1st query will have items in ascending order and the second query will have them in descending order.